# Angular test failing when running in azure pipeline

Tags: angular, azure-pipelines, karma-jasmine

My Angular unit tests are failing, when I am running azure pipeline. I am able to run tests locally without any issue.
Error which I am getting in pipeline is :
[karma-server]:

```
UnhandledRejection: Error: callback(): The callback was already called.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3vmP.png)

-Tried running locally

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing the error message, but also the code itself, a [mre]. We are not clairvoyant, so we cannot help you to debug code you do not show us. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Additionally, [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Your question does not show any part of file or line of code which caused the issue. If possible just add the specific test case which you found is failing on azure.

Comment: My node version was 18 and npm was 9.3, I changed it to 16.x version and it worked

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.